# Laravel 5.6 - Issue passing from jQuery to Laravel Controller

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.6

I'm having some problems passing from my blade file with an ajax request, to my Laravel controller. As far as I can tell I have set up my routes appropriately.

Route

```
Route::post('/aquarium/{id}/parameters', 'AquariumController@paramUpdate')->name('paramUpdate');
```

Laravel Function

```
use App\Aquarium;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

public function paramUpdate($id)
{
    $params = $_POST['parameters'];
    $aquarium = Aquarium::find($id);

    $aquarium->parameters = $params;

    $aquarium->save();

    return "test";
    //return redirect('/aquarium/'.$id);
}
```

Ajax request

```
var jsonParams = JSON.stringify(params);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "{{ route('paramUpdate', $aquarium->id) }}",
    data: { parameters: jsonParams },
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function() {
        console.log("Ajax error");
    }
});
```

The goal is to pass the jsonParams variable to the controller, and then save it to the parameters field in the database. The database is configured and a record exists.

Comment: param updates expects $id. Try using $request in param or if it does not worl try Input::all(). Use dd as needed to see what you get in the function and in inspect element check in the network tab what the result of dd() is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it - I added

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

to the header, and then

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

to the script. Figured it out by using the network tab to see the error being returned, and then some googling from there.